# LINQ groupby on conditional columns

Tags: linq

I am building a report from a table that contains the details of a medical chart audit.  The significant columns are:

```
[ProcedureCode] char(5) = Procedure / service performed
[ModifierCode1] varchar(2) = Indicator of non-standard delivery of procedure
[AuditIssueId] int = what was wrong with the use of the procedure and/or modifier code
```

There may be 0 or many rows per chart.  Two of the AuditIssueIds are for:

1. Incorrect procedure code
2. Incorrect modifier code

The report groups results by the AuditIssue with subgroups by provider and then each procedure or modifier code reviewed (with counts of all charts / issues found / percent).  Here is the first query that gets the chart count:

```
            var providerCharts =
            from ad in db.AuditDetails
            join p in providers on ad.ProviderId equals p.ProviderId
            where ad.ReviewDate >= startDate && ad.ReviewDate <= endDate
            && (filterSpecialtyId == 0 || p.Specialty.SpecialtyId == filterSpecialtyId)
            group ad by new { ad.ProviderId, ad.ProcedureCode } into grpIssue
            select new
            {
                ProviderId = grpIssue.Key.ProviderId,
                ProcedureCode = grpIssue.Key.ProcedureCode,
                ChartCount = grpIssue.Count()
            };
```

This works great, except for one AuditIssue - "Incorrect Modifier Code".  This code shows the count for each procedure in the chart but should instead be grouped by modifier.

I have attempted to insert a condition such as this in my grouping with no luck:

```
(i.AuditIssueId == AuditIssueIds.IncorrectModifierCode) 
? ad.ModifierCode1 : ad.ProcedureCode
```

Do I need to do two queries and union them, or is there a method to achieve this type of dynamic grouping?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: I'm going to assume that you are using LINQ2SQL instead of LINQ over EF because the above should work fine in LINQ over EF.  Tested with `Listings.GroupBy(x=>x.id==4?1:0)` which ran just fine, but that's over EF.

Comment: Odd, I'm not having an issue with LINQ2SQL either, and the following query works just fine: `from x in Listings
group x by (x.Id==4?x.Phone2:x.Phone) into y
select y`

Comment: @RobertMcKee - I am going to have to assume that I simply blew it when trying to code the query.  This does indeed work fine.  Thank you for your comments.